# Using the Facebook graph API, is it possible to get the longitude and latitude from the location object?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The rest of the code works and returns me the values that I am looking for. The last two lines of the code are incorrect. From what I have understand based on Facebooks documentation (i could be misreading something), location objects do store longitude and latitude, but I can not figure out how to access this stuff.

Here is the excerpt of my code:

```
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
 echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'] . "<br />";
 echo "Gender: : "  . $user_profile['gender'] . "<br />";
 echo "Birthday: " . $user_profile['birthday']. "<br />";
 echo "Religion: " . $user_profile['religion']. "<br />";
 echo "Hometown: " . $user_profile['hometown']['name']. "<br />";
 $locationName = $user_profile['location']['name'];
 echo "Location: " . $location . "<br />";
 echo "Longitude: " . $user_profile['location']['']. "<br />";
 echo "Latitude: " . $user_profile['location']['']. "<br />";
```

Comment: `var_dump($user_profile)` would show what you've got to work with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me, I currently get back this data

```
  "location": {
    "id": "109873549031485", 
    "name": "Longmont, Colorado"
  },
```

you can then get the id by using

```
id =['location']['id']
```

then make another graph call to

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/' + id,'GET');
```

which will then provide an object that has the lat / long

```
 "location": {
    "latitude": 40.1672, 
    "longitude": -105.101
  },
```

Comment: "not by default" means that the user didn't give his permission ("user_status ") to access the data!

Comment: And, it's not true that there's no location field for the user, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#fields It just doesn't contain lat/lng

Comment: This actually something more along the lines of something I already tried to do. However after I grabbed the location id and attempted to make another call for the longitude, it would return anything.

Comment: After some tinkering I grabbed longitude and Latitude. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FQL query to achieve this. The lat/lng fields are not available via the Graph API. So you can query like the following (given that you have requested the appropriate permissions for these fields/connections):

```
select name, sex, birthday, religion, hometown_location.city, hometown_location.latitude, hometown_location.longitude, current_location.city, current_location.latitude, current_location.longitude from user where uid=me()
```

which give you something similar to

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "TestUser",
      "sex": "male",
      "birthday": "February 7, 1980",
      "religion": "Catholic",
      "hometown_location": {
        "city": "berlin",
        "latitude": 42.2544,
        "longitude": 8.84583
      },
      "current_location": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "latitude": 55.25,
        "longitude": 12.4
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to change your code to something like

```
$user_profile= $facebook->api( array(
                         'method' => 'fql.query',
                         'query' => 'select name, sex, birthday, religion, hometown_location.city, hometown_location.latitude, hometown_location.longitude, current_location.city, current_location.latitude, current_location.longitude from user where uid=me()',
                     ));
echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'] . "<br />";
echo "Gender: : "  . $user_profile['sex'] . "<br />";
echo "Birthday: " . $user_profile['birthday']. "<br />";
echo "Religion: " . $user_profile['religion']. "<br />";
echo "Hometown City: " . $user_profile['hometown_location']['city']. "<br />";
echo "Hometown Lat: " . $user_profile['hometown_location']['latitude']. "<br />";
echo "Hometown Lng: " . $user_profile['hometown_location']['longitude ']. "<br />";
echo "Current City: " . $user_profile['current_location']['city']. "<br />";
echo "Current Lat: " . $user_profile['current_location']['latitude']. "<br />";
echo "Current Lng: " . $user_profile['current_location']['longitude ']. "<br />";
```

Comment: Sorry if I seem kind of lost but I don't know much about FQL. I copied that code exactly and am getting no data back. Is there something else I am missing? Possibly with permissions? Also is there any good documentations on FQL that you direct me to? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you already accepted the other answer, so I guess this is no longer of interest...

Comment: As of August 8 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried.